# All xml file is redirected to my home page on nginx wordpress yoast

Tags: xml, wordpress, nginx, sitemap, yoast

Hello all my XML files are redirected to the home page, I added this in Nginx as recommended on this page: https://yoast.com/help/xml-sitemaps-nginx/

```
#Yoast SEO Sitemaps
location ~ ([^/]*)sitemap(.*).x(m|s)l$ {
  ## this rewrites sitemap.xml to /sitemap_index.xml
  rewrite ^/sitemap.xml$ /sitemap_index.xml permanent;
  ## this makes the XML sitemaps work
  rewrite ^/([a-z]+)?-?sitemap.xsl$ /index.php?yoast-sitemap-xsl=$1 last;
  rewrite ^/sitemap_index.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
  rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;
  ## The following lines are optional for the premium extensions
  ## News SEO
  rewrite ^/news-sitemap.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=wpseo_news last;
  ## Local SEO
  rewrite ^/locations.kml$ /index.php?sitemap=wpseo_local_kml last;
  rewrite ^/geo-sitemap.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=wpseo_local last;
  ## Video SEO
  rewrite ^/video-sitemap.xsl$ /index.php?yoast-sitemap-xsl=video last;
}
```

i add

```
/(.*)sitemap(.*).xml
/(.*)sitemap.xsl
```

in Never Cache URL(s) in WP Rocket.

I also updated the permalink structure as recommended.

The link "https://www.mywebsite.com/?sitemap=1" works but when i click on any XML link it is redirected to the homepage!

I also tried to install "XML Sitemaps plugin" but it is also redirected to the home page!

I use cloudflare ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by just this code

```
# Rewrites for Yoast SEO XML Sitemap
rewrite ^/sitemap_index.xml$ /?sitemap=1 last;
rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml$ /?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;
```

i just remove index.php !